# IF/ELSE PHP shorthand

Tags: php, shorthand-if

I'm struggling the past couple of hours to write in **shorthand** the PHP conditional statement below:

```
public static $url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

if (false !== strpos($url,'en')) {
    $currlang = 'en';
} else {
    $currlang = 'fr';
}
```

I can't figure out how to do this although I have tried many variations and I've also read online examples. Can you please help?

Comment: `if (strpos($url,'en') !== false)...` makes more sense when you read the code.

Comment: @MarkBiek Maybe you missed the last sentence of my question. I needed some help because I couldn't make it work myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$currlang = false !== strpos($url, 'en') ? 'en' : 'fr';
```

[PHP Manual: Ternary Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

Comment: Thanks! That was fast. I need more practice to understand the logic.