# shorthand php if{} ELSE IF{} else{}

Tags: php, shorthand, shorthand-if

is there a possibility to write a shorthand if, ELSE IF, else statement for php.

if / else is clear but is there a shorthanded way when i want to use elseif too (except switch)?

```
if ($typeArray == 'date'){
    echo 'date';
} else if($typeArray == 'time'){
    echo 'time';
} else {
    echo 'text';
}
```

Haven't found any good answer else, where there is a shorthand version for nested if statements including an elseif.

greetings timmi

Comment: use oop PHP you can achieve this consider each case as a method name.

Comment: That's as short as it's going to get while keeping your sanity.

Comment: There are TERNARY OPERATORS, they offer something like this (and I'm too lazy to write a full answer currently) :)

Comment: dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026612/if-else-php-shorthand?rq=1

Comment: there are so much duplicates of this that you can choose which one to pick, that is a duplicate of other, that is a dup of other, and so on..

Comment: It is recommended that you avoid "stacking" ternary expressions. PHP's behaviour when using more than one ternary operator within a single statement is non-obvious. Source: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Comment: Could you show a piece of code that warrants such a shorthand?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You're looking for [ternary statements](http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

Syntax:

```
$condition ? $value_if_true : $value_if_false
```

Syntax for nested ternary statements:

```
$a ? $b : ( $c ? $d : ( $e ? $f : $g ) )
```

Just a warning, nested ternary statements are hard to read, so it's recommended to unnested ternary statements.

Comment: Ugh, don't ever recommend nested ternary statements, that make code so hard to read

Comment: @BrandonWamboldt It can make it hard to read, but it is what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @jeroen Yeah, but like the answer below, it's good to mention why it's bad to use, so people new to programming don't think it's good practice.

Comment: @BrandonWamboldt That is definitely true.

Comment: hmm yes this suddenly seems like bad idea :D

Answer (score 4):

You can see this [Ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). Good when you have an if/else, but bad readability if you do more.

[Alternative syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php). This syntax is useful when you use html/php in the same code. It helps us to see the end of if/foreach/while...

[switch/case](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php). The best is probably to post some code to see if it could be shortened.